Configure VS Studio Code to open a new file type associated with a plugin
I added easylanguage support plugin to vs studio code so that I can edit code from bollinger.eld file, then modified associations in json.settings but still get vs studio code error message: "The file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding" after clicking on file in vs studio code and provides me with the ability to open with
"open anyway">"Text Editor Active and Default Built In"
"open anyway">"Configure default edtior for *.ELD" (as is explained in the linked post)
But from my understanding that behavior should not be happening based on the way in which I set up my settings.json file
Settings.json     
{ 
      "window.title": "${folderName} - ${remoteName}",
    
      // Python-specific settings
      "[python]": {
        "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off"
      },
      "python.terminal.launchArgs": [],  // Python terminal settings
      "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "",
      "python.createEnvironment.contentButton": "show",
    
      //File associations
      "files.associations": {
        "*.py": "python",  // Python files
        "*.eld": "easylanguage",  // Associate .eld files with EasyLanguage
        "*.easylanguage": "easylanguage",  // EasyLanguage mode for .easylanguage files
        "*.el": "easylanguage",  // EasyLanguage mode for .el files
        "*.elf": "easylanguage"  // EasyLanguage mode for .elf files
      },
      "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,  // Let VS Code guess encoding for files
      "files.encoding": "utf8",  // Default encoding for all files
    
      // Editor behavior for specific file types
      "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.copilotmd": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor",  // Markdown preview for .copilotmd
        "*.ldt": "default"  // Default editor for .ldt files
      },
    
      // General editor and language settings
      "git.autofetch": true,
      "workbench.editor.editorActionsLocation": "titleBar",
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",
      "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
      "git.confirmSync": false,
      "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
      "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {},
      "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "window.zoomLevel": -1,
      "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
      "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
      "editor.rename.enablePreview": false,
      "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
      "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    
      // Auto-complete suggestions settings
      "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
      "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
      "editor.suggest.filterGraceful": true,
      "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true,
      "editor.autoIndent": "advanced"
    }

Encrypted in eld file


Is the bollinger.eld file you are trying to open, a text file? Can you open it (and read its content) using Notepad/TextEdit or something similar? If it is not a text file, the association you have made will have no effect to the extension, because it only supports text files.

I aded a picture of the encrypted file opened as text. I also linked the actual file download so you can reproduce behavior from my question. you can download and scan it in virus total which I did here: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/34ef4b499b499d2c509c3ea276608cf82978a06d87631bee2b9842cee9d125a1?nocache=1

This is not a “text file”, that’s why the setting doesn’t work. The extension you are using only support “text files”, so you must open a feature request to the extension author in order to make it to work with this file format. Because the file is not “plain text”, the extension author needs to encode/decode the file. Depending on how it adds support, maybe you won’t even need this setting anymore.
